# Confused about the following two results

Tags: javascript, string, prototype, instanceof

```
var str = "hello world";
console.log(str.__proto__ === String.prototype); // true
console.log(str instanceof String); // false
```

The str represent a primitive string in this demo.
Now that why its `__proto__` is equal to the contructor's `prototype` ?
And I wonder what exactly does `instanceof` mean ?

Comment: Hi, I guess your question is about JavaScript. Please make sure you have the correct programming language tags in your post.

Comment: The prototype is more similar to inheritance, it's not enough to make an object an instance of another object. The `instanceof` operator checks the `constructor`, which is not present in a string literal